# Python: Changing a pre-defined variable inside if a function

Tags: python

I'm working on a code for a 'casino' in Python (no GUI yet, just trying to get the codes down for now). I want coins to be a system of currency, and I have a perfectly fine Russian Roulette code. If the player survives, I want the code to add onto the player's coins. Said coins are already defined at the top of the code, outside of the function.
When I try

```
return coins += 100
```

at the `elif` clause for the player's survival, I immediately get "invalid syntax" in IDLE.
How can I have the function modify 'coins'?

Comment: *coins are already defined at the top of the code, outside of the function* this can be, but is usually not a good idea.

Comment: removed IDLE tag since this has nothing to do with using the IDE itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're using `coins` as a `global` variable:

```
>>> coins = 0
>>> 
>>> def f():
...     global coins  # <--
...     coins += 100  # notice also that we're not returning anything
... 
>>> f()
>>> 
>>> coins
100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `return 100`
And the caller code would be like `coins += russianRoulette()`
That should work

Comment: ... if, e. g., `russianRoulette()` raises and exception on "deadly hit".

Answer (score 0):

Use coins as a function parameter then return that value with the addition:

```
coins=2

def f(coins):
    return coins+100

>>> f(coins)  
102
```

Or just assign coins the value returned:

```
>>> coins=f(coins)
>>> coins
102
>>> coins=f(coins)
>>> coins
202
```